# Unable to edit content using admin part

Tags: umbraco, umbraco-blog

I have to support a website developed in umbraco. I am totally new to this and this is am working on this for the very first time. My requirement is very straight-I need to edit the content of a webpage. When I too the page it opened with two tabs - Main Content and Properties. In the main content tab I can edit the Title, Banner image, Content header etc, but not the content of the page. It doesn't give any rich textbox to edit the content. I have uploaded the view of one of the page.[image]

I need urgently need to edit the content.Please help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The screenshot implies that the content should be under the "Content" headline in the right screen, but depending on how the documenttype for the frontpage i created, the content could be made up by sub nodes. try folding out the tree to see.

If it dos-nt make sence you can see what documentype a node is made on and what template it uses to display it by clicking the Properties tab. Then go to the Settings Tab in the bottom and see what that documenttype contains and how its displayed in the template